# UIBarButton on UINavigationController So It Applies on All Subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Basically what I want to accomplish is to have a button on the navigation bar so when the view underneath is is pushed, the button stays the same, without having to replace the button on every view. So the view hierarchy would look like this:

Navigation Controller -> First View -> Second View

In this way, the button would be visible on the first view and then after the second view appears, the button would stay.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Approach would be to:

1. Write a SuperViewController class
2. In viewDidLoad add the button to the navigation controller and configure its action
3. Make FirstViewController and SecondViewController subclasses of SuperViewController